# Get an element with specific parent

Tags: javascript

I want to get an element that it's parent has a specific id in javascript. For example if we have an html code like this

```
<div id="1">
 <p name="para"> first div </p>
 <a> </a> 
</div>
<div id="2">
 <p name="para"> second div </p>
 <a> </a>
</div>
<div id="3">
 <p name="para"> third div </p>
 <a> </a>
</div>
```

I tried this but it did not work.

```
document.getElementById('1').getElementByName("para").innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [queryselector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
document.querySelector('#1 > [name=para]').innerHTML = "";
```

**Side note:** [Id's shouldn't start with a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). This could cause issues.

> **Note:** Using characters except ASCII letters, digits, '_', '-' and '.' may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4. Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start with a letter for compatibility.

A simple way to fix the `id` problem would be to prefix the id with something that isn't a number such as an underscore (You will also need to change the html to use an underscore as well):

```
document.querySelector('#_1 > [name=para]').innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: I'm using chrome

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("2").childNodes[1].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelector, but with a unicode as ids shouldn't start with numbers.

```
document.querySelector('#\\33 > p[name="para"]').innerHTML = 'Foo';
```

```js
document.querySelector('#\\33 > p[name="para"]').innerHTML = 'Foo';
```

```html
<div id="1">
 <p name="para"> first div </p>
 <a> </a> 
</div>
<div id="2">
 <p name="para"> second div </p>
 <a> </a>
</div>
<div id="3">
 <p name="para"> third div </p>
 <a> </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it. Note that using `querySelector` is preferred way of doing it as the other answers showed.

```js
const el = document.getElementById('1').childNodes;
const para = [...el]
  .filter(item => item.nodeType === document.ELEMENT_NODE)
  .filter(item => item.tagName === 'P');

console.log(para[0]);
```

```html
<div id="1">
 <p name="para"> first div </p>
 <a> </a>
</div>
<div id="2">
 <p name="para"> second div </p>
 <a> </a>
</div>
<div id="3">
 <p name="para"> third div </p>
 <a> </a>
</div>
```